# Numbering in Align

Tags: align, amsmath

I am looking to remove the numbering from some equations using align and text (see MWE). I have read many posts on this page and tried adding `\nonumber` and `\notag` at the end of my second equation and have received error messages.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

"Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'Equ:ConeAng' will be lost. \end{align}" with \notag

```
\documentclass[english,10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\shortintertext{Radial difference outside diameter and inside diameter of the cone. (in)}
C &= \cfrac{B-A}{2} \label{Equ:C} = \;B'-A' 
\intertext{Cone angle. (degrees)}
E &= tan^{-1}\left(\cfrac{C}{D}\right) \label{Equ:ConeAng}
\intertext{Diagonal length of flat cone. (in)}
F &= \cfrac{C}{sin(E)} \label{Equ:DiagL} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indent code with the [ {} ] button...

Comment: would it be simpler to set them as a series of `equation` environments?  There's no real need for `align` here...

Comment: i think that the `\shortintertext{...}` needn't be within the scope of `align`, and it really isn't "short"; but the other two `\intertext{...}` entries *are* short.  also, i believe that there should be `\\ ` at the ends of the lines before the `\intertext` bits, and that there is a warning in your log file saying that these have been added (silently).  (unfortunately, i'm not somewhere that i can check this easily.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\label` does not work in the unnumbered equation. The equation environments of `amsmath` need to do some special treatment for the `\label` support, which restricts the `\label` commands to one per numbered equation.
Without `\label`, the commands `\nonumber` or `\notag` are working:

```
\documentclass[english,10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\shortintertext{Radial difference outside diameter and inside diameter of the co
C &= \cfrac{B-A}{2} \label{Equ:C} = \;B'-A'
\intertext{Cone angle. (degrees)}
E &= \tan^{-1}\left(\cfrac{C}{D}\right) \nonumber
\intertext{Diagonal length of flat cone. (in)}
F &= \cfrac{C}{\sin(E)} \label{Equ:DiagL}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]